# Insert after each opening tag

Tags: php

How do I use `preg_replace` to insert a given string after each opening tag in a string containing HTML? For example, if I have the string:

```
$str = 'sds<some_tag>ttt</some_tag>dfg<some_tag>vvv</some_tag>sdf';
```

and I want to insert `<b>`, the result should be:

```
$str = 'sds<some_tag><b>ttt</some_tag>dfg<some_tag><b>vvv</some_tag>sdf';
```

Comment: [Perseverance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464477/how-to-do-it-it-doesnt-work-for-now): You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Question is still as clear as mud.

Comment: I think he's asking how would he go about inserting a string (in his example above a '<b>') in between some tags he defined (<some_tag) in his example) ?

Comment: @PHPguru I tried to rewrite your question as best as I could understand it and [the other version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464477/how-to-do-it-it-doesnt-work-for-now); if it's not accurate please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3464562/edit) yourself to clarify what you're actually asking for

Comment: @Michael Mrozek The question still isn't clear. Presumably, he want's a </b> as well. And I hope he doesn't really want nested <b>'s

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty of adding closing tags for you. If this is really not the desired behavior, then just send in the first member of each array instead of the array itself.

```
$str = 'sss<some_tag with="attributes">ttt</some_tag>dfg';
$str .= '<some_tag with="other[] attributes" and="still-more-attributes">';
$str .= 'vvv</some_tag>sdf';


function embolden($string, $some_tag)
{
    //make our patterns
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[] = '/<'.$some_tag.'(.*)>/U';
    $patterns[] = '/<\/'.$some_tag.'(.*)>/U';

    // without the non-greedy `U` modifier, we'll clobber most of the string. 
    // We also use capturing groups to allow for replacing any attributes that
    // might otherwise get left behind. We can use multiple capturing groups in 
    // a regular expression and refer to them in the replacement strings as $n
    // with n starting at 1

    //make our replacements
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[] = '<'.$some_tag.'$1><b>';
    $replacements[] = '</b></'.$some_tag.'$1>';

    return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
}

//htmlentities for convienent browser viewing
$output = embolden($str, 'some_tag');
echo htmlentities($str);
echo '<br>';
echo htmlentities($output);
```